# Django ORM Queryset class behave different with same filters

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

This is a simple question.

I want to 2 filters at once with Queryset class. Let me explain.

```
from django.db.models import Q
import datetime
from .models import Asset

query_set = Asset.objects.filter(category__name="car")

date_query = {'eav__date__gte': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 2, 0, 0), 'eav__date__lte': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 14, 0, 0)}

number_query = {'eav__price__gte': '60', 'eav__price__lte': '600'}

total_query = {'eav__date__gte': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 2, 0, 0), 'eav__date__lte': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 14, 0, 0),'eav__price__gte': '60', 'eav__price__lte': '600'}
```

---

```
query_set = query_set.filter(Q(**number_query))

query_set = query_set.filter(Q(**date_query))
```

in this case, query_set is **not** empty!

---

```
query_set = query_set.filter(Q(**total_query))
```

in this case, query_set is empty!

---

Might someone explain the difference between two query please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you print the two queries (with `print(str(query_set.query))`? I have the impression that the original `query_set` might already be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are filtering across a many-valued relationship. As [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) explain:

> Django has a consistent way of processing `filter()` calls. Everything inside a single `filter()` call is applied simultaneously to filter out items matching all those requirements. Successive `filter()` calls further restrict the set of objects, but for multi-valued relations, they apply to any object linked to the primary model, not necessarily those objects that were selected by an earlier `filter()` call.

So, your first case selects all those Assets with an EAV which matches the date requirements and an EAV which matches the price requirements, but *not necessarily the same EAV*. Your second case selects only those Assets for which there is an EAV which matches *both* requirements at the same time.

Comment: Does that assume that those 2 lines `query_set = query_set.filter(Q(**number_query))  query_set = query_set.filter(Q(**date_query))` are tested one by one separately? But what if they both are applied in the code one after another? Wouldn't that be the same `&` operation?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The point is only that they are in different `filter()` calls.

Comment: I mean running those 2 filters 1 by 1 is the same, that `query_set = query_set.filter(Q(**number_query)).filter(Q(**date_query))`? And that is the same that filtering on `**total_query`?

Comment: But I've just explained why they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use Q object to build query set.
Its easiest way to work with queries in Django
IN your case

```
query_set = query_set.filter(Q(**number_query))
query_set = query_set.filter(Q(**date_query))
```

These are different querysets.

```
query_set = query_set.filter(Q(**total_query))
```

Here you are combining two queries without AND ,OR condition so it's empty.
Here you want AND condition I think so use this like
    Q(first_name__startswith='R') & Q(last_name__startswith='D')